# How can I set a cursor to a dynamically created SQL query in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, database-cursor

I want to create a dynamic command using @sqlQuery variable.  I've also declared a cursor (example: @myCursor).  How can I "SET @myCursor = CURSOR FOR @sqlQuery".  The syntax I just noted doesn't work.  I am using SQL 2000.

Comment: So many things are wrong with this...

Comment: Or you could not use a cursor which is the preferred approach. Cursors are extremely bad for performance in SQL Server and should never be the first choice of a technique. Something like 95% of all cursors (in my personal experience) can be replaced with set-based code. Doing it dynamically is even worse as it is impossible to fully test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `sp_executesql`. Just be sure to open the cursor within the dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OpenCursor (@query nvarchar(max), @cur cursor VARYING OUTPUT)
AS
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
    SET @sql = N'SET @cur = CURSOR STATIC FOR ' + @query + '; OPEN @cur'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@cur cursor OUTPUT', @cur OUTPUT
GO

DECLARE @cur cursor
EXEC OpenCursor 'SELECT * FROM sysobjects', @cur OUTPUT
FETCH NEXT FROM @cur
```